# TkInter Radiobuttons placing each option on top of eachother

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to implement a 4-option radiobutton, however, whenever I try to Place the radiobutton inside the window, each option gets placed on top of each other, instead of one below the other:

```
MODES = [
        ("First ", "1"),
        ("Second", "L"),
        ("Third ", "RGB"),
        ("Fourth", "CMYK")
]

answer = StringVar()
answer.set("L")

for text, mode in MODES:
    RB = Radiobutton(root, text=text, variable = answer, value = mode, font  = ("Segoe UI", 14), )
RB.place(x=20, y=90)
```

However, when I Pack the radiobutton, and not Place the radiobutton, it seems to place the options one below the other, so is there a way to use the Place function, and still have the options display one below the other? Thanks in advance. Here's a screenshot for reference:

[As you can see, there's only one option being displayed, and all the others are underneath.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDu2U.png)

Comment: The code you posted here only makes one Radiobutton visible, since the `.place()` is outside the loop, and only applies to the final button.  If that line was properly indented, then you'd get all of the buttons in the same position, since you're giving them all the same coordinates - what other outcome could you possibly imagine?  `.pack()` and `.grid()` are the tools Tkinter provides for laying out widgets nicely, use them!

Comment: Place gives you complete control. You can put them anywhere you want. Just do a little math on the coordinates.

Comment: @BryanOakley that's the problem, I want precise control over there my widgets go, however in this case the place functions seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @Jasonharper I wanted to offset my radio buttons to the right by 20 pixels instead of having the widgets stuck to the side, which is why I used place

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If you want precise control, `place` is absolutely the best solution, since you can specify to the pixel where a widget goes, and how wide and tall it is. Though, 99.99% of the time, precise control is not what you really want. `pack` and `grid` make it much easier to create GUIs that scale well when resolution, window size, and/or font sizes change.

Comment: if you don't want the buttons to stick to the edge of the frame use the `padx` and `pady` arguments of `pack()`

Comment: @rioV8 Unfortunately the padx/pady does not work as intended. The padx works, however, as the value for pady increases, the radiobuttons stretch vertically. I have used the statement: `RB.pack(anchor = W, padx = 20, pady = 40)`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Firas, telling what you want to achieve is more informative. The image you supply does not show what you want to have eventually (next to what you now have).

Comment: @rioV8 well what I currently achieve is this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDu2U.png

And what I want is this:
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=tkinter+radiobutton&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic_vCh-6_cAhVPXMAKHRgtCnsQ_AUICigB&biw=1239&bih=601#imgrc=mvZcwbSs6ZeaDM:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code fragment will show the radio buttons in a vertical stack. I used an additional `tk.Frame` to get a padding from the window to the controls (only need to specify this once for all controls).

```
import tkinter as tk

MODES = [
        ("First ", "1"),
        ("Second", "L"),
        ("Third ", "RGB"),
        ("Fourth", "CMYK")
]

root = tk.Tk()

answer = tk.StringVar()
answer.set("L")

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill=tk.BOTH)

tk.Label(frame, text="Choose your language:").pack()

for text, mode in MODES:
    RB = tk.Radiobutton(frame, text=text, variable = answer, value = mode)
    RB.pack(anchor="w")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the problem, I think I was missing the `fill=BOTH` part!